# Submitting a Short Code Application in US

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I'm not familiar with the process for enabling MobileConnect short codes in the US (as the process for MobileConnect enablement differs by country and I'm based in Australia).

One of my US clients has been informed by their Account Executive that they can only engage one of four accredited Partners, which are listed in [this thread](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000surzQAA). Salesforce explained that these Partners are 'trained' in how to complete the provisioning form, which apparently is long and if you provide the incorrect information, it can significantly delay the provisioning process.

Other Partners need a [paid?] PSS engagement to submit the application on their behalf.

Can someone confirm this? Is it really true that there are only four US Partners who can submit a short code application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have to engage one of our approved partners to have them provision with the carriers -- though I'm not sure if those four are the current partners. I believe Salesforce used to use MGage, but now it's SAP which gives a faster turn around time (previous time line was 16-20 weeks
and now it is about 12-14 weeks and usually less).

Alternatively, you can acquire the shortcode yourself and have it migrated over to MobileConnect, but it still goes through a similar process.

Being "trained" on it is simply filling out Marketing Cloud's Campaign Approval Form (CAF) which asks you for basic information like:

- Subscription Management (Optin Keywords, Opt-Out keywords),
- Message Flow (Call to Action, Confirmation message), and
- Terms and Conditions/Privacy Policy live on your site or verbiage if it's not live yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is accurate, a partner can become mobile certified to accomplish this task in the future